# retrieve the substring after the first slash

Tags: javascript, extjs5

I have a String like the following pattern:

```
string1 / string2 / string3
```

I want to get the following as end string:

```
string2 / string3
```

I am doing that with the code below. Is there a better way in Javascript to manage that?

**code**

```
var key = 'door / chair / screw';
var keyArray = key.replace('/', ', ');
var endKey = keyArray[1];
```

Comment: `key.substring(key.indexOf('/ ') + 2)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is by using `split`, `slice` and `join`.

```js
var key = 'door / chair / screw';
console.log(key.split(' / ').slice(1).join(' / '));
```

Or if you want to do it by replace, here is a way:

```js
var key = 'door / chair / screw';
console.log(key.replace(/\w+\s+\/\s+/, ''));
```

Comment: Or you can match specific part: `str.match(/\/ (.*)/)[1]`